# How to lazily set data on two RecyclerViews, so that the user thinks both RecyclerViews are setting records one at a time?

Tags: java, android

I have two RecycleViews, one for pinning sessions and one for unpinning sessions. When I load the session data first set the data to the pinning recyclerview and then set the data to the unpinned recyclerview.
I want to set the data on the recyclerview as lazy type so that the user should get the feeling that both the Recyclerviews are setting one by one record at a time.
So how to do that?